# Picker is not working when it has only one value

Tags: codenameone

I'm using picker.setStrings() method. It works fine when there are more than one value in the string array but does nothing when there is only one element in the array. In the code below if I uncomment the commented statements, it works fine (shows the no in dialog box) but with one element it is not working (shows blank in dialog box msg). 
PS. It works all right in simulator but in devices, there exists this problem.

```
Picker stationPicker = new Picker();
stationPicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
stationPicker.setSelectedString("Select the service center");

stationArray = new String[1];
stationArray[0] = "abc";
//  stationArray[1] = "def";

stationPicker.setStrings(stationArray);
stationPicker.getParent().revalidate();

stationPicker.addActionListener(e -> {
    stationIdArray = new String[1];
//  stationIdArray = new String[2];
    stationIdArray[0] = "1";
//  stationIdArray[1] = "2";

    if (stationArray != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < stationArray.length; i++) {
            if (stationPicker.getSelectedString().equals(stationArray[i])) {
            selectedStationId = stationIdArray[i] + "";
            }
        }
    }
    Dialog.show("Result", selectedStationId, "ok", null);
}
```

Comment: Which devices is this failing on?  Android, iOS, etc..?

Comment: android Samsung... J7 prime and other Samsung devices too

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  This looks like it was a bug in the Android implementation of the picker.  I have [fixed](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/5186ff4355ed79130979d1b70d96d5283bd0e0dd) this in github, and it will be included in the next server update on Friday.